# Delphi XE10, can't edit field values of an empty TQuery

Tags: delphi, tquery

I have a dataset, TQuery object with property Requestlive=TRUE, Tdatasource and a TDBgrid, connected. When the query returns empty i face this problem : Trying to add the first record, i can't edit the fields of it.
After saving this (empty) first record, i can continue normaly (adding, editing etc).
What can i do to avoid this problem, please ?

Comment: Quitting BDE isn't an option for this case.
You missundestood me. I try to add a new (the first) record to the dataset. 
Actualy, the dataset has already records but this problem occurs when my query returns empty (eg. There are records for 2016 but not for 2017. So when i try to add the first record for 2017, i face this problem)

Comment: I'm not sure I did misunderstand you.  Ok, your database table (the server-side one) contains records, but the query your TQuery executes returns zero records.  Therefore you have an empty client-side dataset.  I'm afraid I don't have any functional BDE databases around to determine how the BDE reacts to that.  Saving your empty record then editing it may be your only option, unless you do an explicit Sql INSERT.

Comment: There is no such thing as XE10. Well, the only thing that goes by that name that I know of is cracked software. Are you using cracked software?

Comment: So ComponentAce (http://www.componentace.com/download/download.php?editionid=1) , or d23 (JEDI project ) or RAD studio 10 (Devart) or many others deal with cracked software ?

Comment: They are making the same mistake as you. The last XE was XE8. After that came 10 Seattle and then 10.1 Berlin.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found the reason that causes this problem but i did this workaround :

```
procedure TFormA.QueryNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
    case Query.RecordCount of
        0 : begin // if dataset is empty then append a fake record
                Query.fieldByname('aDate').AsDateTime := now;
                Query.fieldByname('fieldA').AsFloat := 0; // fieldA is a mantatory field 
                Query.Post;
            end;
        else Query.fieldByname('aDate').AsDateTime := now; 
    end;
end;
```

and in the onCloseForm event i add this :

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM NOTES WHERE fieldA=0';
Query.ExecSQL;
```

to delete any fake record appended this way